# Do I have to worry about signing transaction?

Tags: truffle, security

I'm using truffle & ganache to test a simple voting app. 
Do I have to worry about security and transaction signing or is it managed for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From my understanding of your question:*

- Normally you just don't need to sign transactions when you are using
  `truffle test`.
- In case you are using some frontend then you are using metamask and
  it simply prompts you to accept a transaction and automatically deals
  with signing.

Answer (score 0):

If truffle is connected to Ganache then it uses first account to perform transaction which is already unlocked , which means no need to sign.

If truffle is connected to main-net or test net, truffles uses truffle-hdwallet-provider to store private key in local machine and signing is required.

Found below article useful, it explain how truffle interacts with Rinkeby and send signed transaction.

https://kauri.io/article/cbc38bf09088426fbefcbe7d42ac679f/truffle:-smart-contract-compilation-and-deployment